# How to Retrieve FireStore Users Within a Range With GeoFireStore Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am currently working on a program which requires containing location of users with Android Studio. In my users collection, I have location informations as geopoints for each user documents. I need to get all users which are in radius range of a circle. I found GeoFireStore of imperiumlabs -https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android- for this geographic location processes. I can set and get location of a document(single user). But I want to define a center and check if there is/are anyone within the range.

As I understand I need to use geo query event listener as follows;

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {...}
```

It has Key Entered, Key Moved, Query Ready, Query Error methods, but I couldn't manage what and how to use. I need returned informations of documents(users) which(who) are in my defined range. This way, I can show them main user.

For short words; can someone help me about understanding event listeners of geofirestore?

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Please don't post the solution as part of your question. Instead post them as a separate answer, which also allows you to accept it as an answer (which flags it in the system). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending more and more hours I finally solved my issue with

> public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint location) {}

in the GeoQueryDataEventListener Interface. This method works recursively until meeting the requirements of query and I put it in onCreate. I just listed document_id's with documentSnapshot.getId() and tranferred them to an arraylist with `mList.add(documentSnapshot.getId())` . Hope this can help someone take care.